# From Js to Dart code translation. Recursion and memoization

Tags: javascript, dart, recursion, multidimensional-array, translate

I'm following a video tutorial on YouTube ( Dynamic Programming - Learn to Solve Algorithmic Problems & Coding Challenges ) from a popular YouTube channel.
In this video it teaches in Js and I'm trying to translate it into Dart, but even when my algorithm looks the same it doesn't work as expected.

This is what the function should do:

- Write a function **'allConstruct(target, wordBank)'** that accepts a target string and an array of strings.
  The function should return a 2D array containing *all of the ways* that the **'target'** can be constructed by concatenating elements of the **'wordBank'** array. Each element of the 2D array should represent one combination that constructs the **'target'**.
  You may reuse elements of **'wordBank'** as many times as needed.

-- Here is the Js code

```
const allConstruct = (target, wordBank) => {
  if (target === '') return [[]];

  const result = [];

  for (let word of wordBank) {
    if (target.indexOf(word) === 0) {
      const suffix = target.slice(word.length);
      const suffixWays = allConstruct(suffix, wordBank);
      const targetWays = suffixWays.map(way => [ word, ...way ]);
      result.push(...targetWays);
    }
  }

  return result;
};
```

-- And here is my Dart translation

```
allContruct(String target, List<String> wordBank) {
  if (target == '') return [[]];

  final result = [];

  for (final word in wordBank) {
    print(word);
    if (target.startsWith(word)) {
      final suffix = target.split(word)[1];
      final suffixWays = allContruct(suffix, wordBank);
      final targetWays = suffixWays.map((way) => [word, ...way]);
      result.insert(0, targetWays);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

With the same input of the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBt53YbR9Kk&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org at 03:03:18
**allContruct('purple',['purp', 'p', 'ur', 'le', 'purpl'])**
here is how it result:

JS : [['purp', 'le'],['p','ur','p','le']]

My Dart: [(), ([p, [ur]]), ([purp, [le]])]

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Could you show an example of input and what result it should give?

Comment: I think can be even more useful to watch the video at 03:03:18, it's just a few seconds and it also makes you better understand what the algorithm is pupposed to do ;)

Comment: You have not linked to any video. Also, it should never be a requirement to watch a video for answering a question on Stackoverflow. All needed information should be in the question.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "but even when my algorithm looks the same it doesn't work as expected.". What behavior do you observe that is problematic?

Comment: Excuse me (: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBt53YbR9Kk&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org

Comment: Here is how my code results with the same input of the video: 
[(), ([p, [ur]]), ([purp, [le]])]

Comment: I have re-edited the question to be more precise as possible, let me know if I've been clear enough )

Comment: It is clear enough now. I have made a working solution but I am doing some cleanup before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code.

First, type safety are important in Dart so I have added types where needed. This is mostly the return type of your method and your declaration of `result` variable where Dart cannot guess what type you want.

Second, the `String.split` method are not the same as `String.slice` from JavaScript. I have replaced that call with [`String.substring`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/String/substring.html).

Third, `result.push` does not push to to the start of the list but instead to the end. But your `result.insert(0, targetWays);` are telling Dart to insert your elements from the `0` position of the list (the beginning).

I have replaced this with `result.addAll` since your `targetWays` are a lazy-evaluated `Iterable`.

With all this changes, I get the same output as you have written. Please tell me if something is not working as expected. And if so, please provide example of the situation where it does not work.

```dart
List<List<String>> allContruct(String target, List<String> wordBank) {
  if (target == '') return [[]];
  final result = <List<String>>[];

  for (final word in wordBank) {
    print(word);
    if (target.startsWith(word)) {
      final suffix = target.substring(word.length);
      final suffixWays = allContruct(suffix, wordBank);
      final targetWays = suffixWays.map((way) => [word, ...way]);
      result.addAll(targetWays);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

void main() {
  print(allContruct('purple', ['purp', 'p', 'ur', 'le', 'purpl']));
  // [[purp, le], [p, ur, p, le]]
}
```